# How do you set top level property methods in a constructor based on a function call?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a constructor in a class that sets properties based on the arguments passed when creating the function as well as a call to another function based on those arguments but I am running into an issue. I have solved in with a work around but there must be a more elegant way to write this (no pun intended).

Here is my constructor:

```
constructor(name,model,version){
// create optional parameters to set basic values
this.name = name;
this.model = model;
this.version = version;

if(model === undefined || version === undefined){
  this.make = "";
  this.model = "";
  this.version = "";
  this.prop3 = 0
  this.prop4 = 0;
  this.prop5 = 0;
}
else{
  this = getVersionAttrs(model,version); }
```

This code does not work, if I replace `this` with `this.what` then the code functions but sets all of the properties as properties of OBJECT.what and not directly of the OBJECT.

I've replaced the else statement with the following that works:

```
else{
  temp = getVersionAttrs(model,version);
  for(var x in temp){ this[x] = temp[x]; }
}
```

Does anyone know how to assign this object I am getting back from the function `getVersionAttrs()` to the object that is being created? Aka properties of the returned object should become properties of the object being created.

Thanks in advance, I've been scratching my head over this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to re-assign a `this`. If `getVersionAttrs` returns an object with properties you want to add to `this`, you should use `Object.assign` instead:

```
else {
  Object.assign(this, getVersionAttrs(model, version));
}
```

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { foo: 'foo' });
  }
}
console.log(new MyClass());
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and simplified my code. Before I was able to set new properties directly by calling this.prop1 = someNewValue but I couldn't figure out how to add multiple properties, or really the object that the function I was calling return. Thanks!

Comment: When answers solve the problem you're having, you can mark them as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying accomplish here, but from what I can see, I believe you should be set with something as simple as this:

```
constructor(name, model=null, version=null){      
  if (!model || !version) {
     var {model, version} = getVersionAttrs(model, version);
  }

  this.name = name;
  this.model = model;
  this.version = version;
}
```

Assuming `getVersionAttrs(model, version)` returns something like `{model: 'model', version: 'version' }`

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha, that is typical wrong. Let us review your code

```
this = getVersionAttrs(model,version);
```

I guess you want to `Object.assign` this value but you re assignment this value.

So, there is a simple solution below, [about Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
this = Object.assign({}, this, getVersionAttrs(model,version))
```

Also you can use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) or other same APIs.

Comment: Thank you, by passing an empty object as the target does this simplify the operation and save resources by just assigning the two sources to the object referenced by this?

Comment: `Object.assign` will change the value of first argument. I think this is more safety use to reassign this value.